how to state a negation of a previous step in a method claim?
method claim:

identifying a first input;
optionally identifying a second input;
in response to identifying the first input, do something;
in response to not identifying the second input, do something else;

Questions:

is it correct to say "in response to not identifying..."
why isn't it "in response to not having identified..."
what about "in response to the second input being unidentified..."


what is it intended to mean by "identify" an input? is the input optional or is the process of identifying it optional? "in response to" evokes some kind of stimulus to me that does not appear to be present. I would consider something like "when the second input is not present, [do something else]" (in case you meant that the second input is optional).

The process of identifying it is optional. In other words, the second input can be completely omitted from the implementation such that there isn't even a way to input the second input.

_Bear, in that case have you considered leaving it out of the independent claim? IIRC, an optional step does not help to distinguish over the prior art. If the optional step is required to distinguish over the prior art, it should not be optional in the claim.

@bhuff36 The optional step involves identifying a value to an input. The input is a named value that is used in a formula late on in the independent claim. There is a wherein clause that states that this input value has a base value of zero if unidentified.

_Bear, that sounds like it might trigger an indefiniteness rejection where you would have quite a weak case to fight it. The problem is that x=0 is a special case of x, so what you are thinking of as the independent claim should actually be the dependent claim. But then you have no way of "removing" any processing related to the input you want to consider optional. There is only so much you can do to avoid paying claim fees.

The “in response” part doesn’t make any sense.
You could say that only in the case of not identifying the second optional input, do something else. But there are probably better ways to say it.
Making the optional required in a dependent claim is probably A better structure

do you mean "in response to identifying the first input" doesn't make sense. As in it doesn't make sense to respond to something not happening?

You can respond to something not happening. If it was “in absence of valid input 2 do something else. In response to inability to unambiguously identify input 2 as valid do something else.

what about "in response to the second input being unidentified..."

If you want a “response” from something not happening it might better to use different wording. When did the non happening happen?
